# Formatting output to resemble a table in C++

Tags: c++

I am using sprintf to format my data. The same output when formatted using printf works well but I cannot use printf as I am using the output data to send an email.

```
for(...)
{
 sprintf(sLuns, "%-50s%-50s%-50s%-3d%-14s", str1, str2, str3, int1, str4);
 string sRow(sLuns);
 sTable = sTable + "\n" + sRow;
}
```

The output of sTable looks like the below. The width is not constant for all columns. Is this because I am converting the row elements into a C String ?

```
Name1      Str1       Str2       10         str3 
Name1      Str1       Str2       10         str3
Name111      Str1       Str2       10         str3
```

Comment: I think you're looking for tab (`\t`) characters !

Comment: I have already given the width size as 50 for strings. Why \t again ?

Comment: C strings will often be smaller than the max width. So you need to whitespace pad your output as well.

Comment: I think that you're just truncating strings with more than 50 characters.

Comment: No way that line could produce the shown output.

Comment: If you are using the output for email would outputting in html be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I see you also have the `C++` tag on your question. So I'll recommend you to use `C++`.

You can use [left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) from `iomanip` to achive what you want.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string str1 = "str1";
string str2 = "str2";
string str3 = "str3";
string str4 = "str4";
int i = 10;

int main()
{
    strstream str;

    str << left
        << setw(10) << str1
        << setw(10) << str2
        << setw(10) << str3
        << setw(10) << i
        << setw(10) << str4
        << endl;

    cout << str.rdbuf() << endl;

}
```